# Java: Stack Implementation

Tags: java, stack

I need to write an exception class, called StackEmptyException based on the following code? It should be a subclass of the RuntimeException class.

```
public interface IStack {
      public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException;
      public void push(Object o);
      public boolean isEmpty();
      public int size();
      public void clear();
}
```

Is this all I need to write?:

```
 public class StackEmptyException extends RuntimeException {

      public StackEmptyException(){
          super();
      }
  }
```

Then, how do I write an implementation of the IStack interface, called Stack. In the event that the user tries to pop() from an empty list, the class should generate an appropriate exception. Your stack should be backed by an array of Objects that should be resized in the event that it becomes full.

I am a beginner so please explain your solutions as if I were a three year old :)

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? If you google "java write exception" you will find a tons of answers. I see that you are member for today and you already ask 5 questions. Maybe you need to think a little more before asking here.

Comment: @zouzou I am stuck because I am not sure if what I have done is correct or if I am missing something. And yes, I post a lot because after reading online and not understanding I hope people on forums can help explain things to me so I can learn :)

Comment: But I don't see what you've done except declaring this single exception class. You should try to implement the interface first and then ask if you have a specific question related. Not "How do I write an implemenation". I mean its your task and you will learn by doing it yourself, not letting the people on SO to answer this. You can ask for specific pointers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class now that implement the interface `IStack`(when `I` for interfaces is kinda too old).
Something like this

```
public class MyStack implement IStack{
      public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException{
        if(size==0){throw new StackEmptyException();}
        //otherwise return the last component. return stack[size--];
      };
      public void push(Object o)throws StackOverFlow{if(size==stack.length-1){throw new StackOverFlow();}};
      public boolean isEmpty(){return size==0;};
      public int size(){return size;};
      public void clear(){size=0;};
      ///////////////
      private Object[] stack;
      private final static default_stack_size=16;
      private boolean can_extended=false;
      public MyStack(){stack=new Object[16];}
      public MyStack(int size){stack=new Object[size];}
}
```

It also depends on way you like to implement the stack, maybe you like to make it extensible or static as size, or many things.

Comment: Not sure about the 'I for interfaces is kinda too old' comment. How else do you label interfaces so that, viewing a series of *.java files, you know which are interfaces easily?

Comment: @Zéychin: You can put the interfaces in a separate package, or you can add Interface to the interface name, like StackInterface.

Comment: I guess it's down to preference at that point. I think saying it was too 'old' was a bit dismissive is all.

Comment: Since I've been dealing with java stuffs for years, I haven't seen any interface named like `IStuff` yet, it's kinda csharp approach. @Zéychin

Comment: Everywhere I've worked has done it. Just a matter of preference is all.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `isEmpty()` implemented you can do `pop()` like this:

```
public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException{
    if(isEmpty()){
         throw new StackEmptyException();
    }else{
         // 
         // return stackLastElement;
    }

}
```

And in push method you need to check whether your vector has space to push object:

```
   public void push(Object o){
       //...
       if(allPositionsInStackAreFille){
           //extend Your Stack
       }
       // put the object onto right place
   }
```